# MVC getting a list of music and image into a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have already plug in the codes for uploading files and its working but the problem is I want upload image to be in image name table, music in music table column.

But the set of codes below is I upload either of them I will get a new column

Here's my table

```
<table class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style = width = "10">
                Image File
            </th>
            <th>
                Image Preview
            </th>
            <th>
               MP3 File
            </th>
            <th>
                Remove 
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Here's my razor html - all my files are upload into a directory, is there a code to get the extension of .jpg into image column and mp3 to mp3 column?

```
      @foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@ViewBag.UploadURL)))
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(f);

            ViewBag.FileNoExtension = fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, fileInfo.Name.IndexOf('.'));
            ViewBag.FileExtension = fileInfo.Name.Substring(fileInfo.Name.IndexOf('.') + 1);
            <tr>
               <td style = width = "10">@fileInfo.Name</td>
                @* <td>@ViewBag.FileNoExtension</td>*@
              <td><img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Content(@ViewBag.UploadURL + "/" + fileInfo.Name)" /></td>


                    <td>
                       // i need the code for this line to populate mp3 files         
                    </td>
                    }
                    <td>            
                      @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = @ViewBag.StoryID, id2 = @ViewBag.FileNoExtension, id3 = @ViewBag.FileExtension })
                    </td>

            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename)` to get the extension? You are better off putting all the work into your controller and not the view. Build a list of "items" (your own class) containing the details the view needs and pass that to the view. The view should remain pretty simple if possible as `cshtml` files get messy fast.

Comment: Please show your controller code, so I can suggest improvements (also a screenshot of the app would be nice)

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed you have some form of common naming to relate the images to the names. For this example I have simply assigned the images to the MP3 files in sequence.

1. Do the messy work in the controller, not your view. Keep views simple.
2. Use a View model for the content that is closer to what your view needs.
3. Get the controller to do the messy work of converting raw facts into the view model.
4. Controller then passes view mode to view to display it.

### Your view should be simple like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeWebApplication.Models.MusicItem>
<table class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image File</th>
            <th>MP3 File</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><img width="50" height="50" src="@item.ImageUrl" /></td>
                <td><embed src="@item.MusicUrl" /></td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = @item.Id })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...it takes a collection of MusicItems as its View Model

### The View Model will look like:

```
public class MusicItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique id of item
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// URL to image
    /// </summary>
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Url to music
    /// </summary>
    public string MusicUrl { get; set; }
}
```

### Your controller should do the heavy lifting:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Story story = db.Stories.Find(id);

        // Use server relative paths for views
        String filepathMusic = "/Upload/story/Music/" + story.FileURL;
        String filepathImage = "/Upload/story/Image/" + story.FileURL;

        // Build a list of MusicItem objects
        List<MusicItem> items = new List<MusicItem>();
        string[] musicFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~" + filepathMusic));
        foreach (var musicFile in musicFiles)
        {
            items.Add(new MusicItem()
            {
                Id = id,
                MusicUrl = filepathMusic + "/" + Path.GetFileName(musicFile)
            });
        }

        // This example simply allocates the images in the order found - need to do this properly
        string[] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~" + filepathImage));
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var imageFile in imageFiles)
        {
            if (index < items.Count)
            {
                items[index].ImageUrl = filepathImage + "/" + Path.GetFileName(imageFile);
            }
            index++;
        }

        return View(items);
    }
```

then, assuming you have 2 images and two files in your story...

### The end result of the test code above looks like this:

[image]

Comment: erm thanks but i not getting from database tats why  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119096/mvc-getting-a-list-of-mp3-and-image-into-a-table

Comment: i added the controllers there, hope theres help ;)

Comment: What has "getting from database" go to do with it? A ViewModel just contains "data". It can be any sort of data from anywhere. It does not have to come from a database. Just build the list of objects from your directory contents. That logic can be as simple or as complex as it needs, but you just want it to combine your images and sound files together. Please provide a sample list of what filenames are in your folder if you need further suggestions.